# How can I properly implement TextChanged event via Commands with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm learning WPF with MVVM pattern. My app is counting Body Mass Index, so it's really simple - just to help me understand the foundations of this pattern.

I was experimenting a little bit and decided to implement TextChanged event via Commands to allow user see changes in overall BMI label while he's typing a height or weight.

My textBoxes in which I use the TextChanged command are binded to ViewModel properties in TwoWay mode, so I thought that if I raise INotifyPropertyChanged event on properties binded to these textBoxes when TextChanged event occurs it will automatically update View, but it doesn't.

So question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I implement it properly?

PS. Everything else excepting View update is working (command is used, I checked with breakpoint it just doesn't change the View)

Thanks in advance

CustomCommand class:

```
public class CustomCommand : ICommand
{

    Action<object> action;
    Predicate<object> predicate;

    public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        action = execute;
        predicate = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (predicate(parameter))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action(parameter);
    }
}
```

One of two textBoxes:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,83,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Person.Weight, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=textChangedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

And ViewModel, where TextChanged method is passed to a command

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;

        if (propertyChanged != null)
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public ICommand textChangedCommand { get; set; }

    //public List<float> BMI_Changed;

    private PersonInfo person;


    public PersonInfo Person
    {
        get
        {
            return person;
        }
        set
        {
            person = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Person");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //BMI_Changed = new List<float>();
        textChangedCommand = new CustomCommand(TextChanged, CanBeChanged);
        person = Data.personInfo;
    }


    private void TextChanged(object obj)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("BMI");
        OnPropertyChanged("Weight");
        OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }

    private bool CanBeChanged(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Rest of my View code, for general overview:

```
<Window x:Class="SportCalculators_MVVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SportCalculators_MVVM"
    xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:SportCalculators_MVVM.Model"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="340.278" Width="260.256" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}, Path=mainWindowViewModel}">

<Grid x:Name="grid">


    <Slider x:Name="mass" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,128,58,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Value="{Binding Person.Weight, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="150" Minimum="20"/>
    <Slider x:Name="height" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Minimum="100" Maximum="230" Value="{Binding Person.Height, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="sex" Content="Kobieta" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Person.Sex, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=genderConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enum:Sex.Female}}"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="sex1" Content="Mężczyzna" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Person.Sex, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=genderConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enum:Sex.Male}}"/>
    <Label x:Name="massLabel" Content="Waga" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="heightLabel" Content="Wzrost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Person.BMI}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,274,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Statystyki" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,274,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.325,-0.438"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,83,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Person.Weight, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=textChangedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,170,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Person.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=textChangedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>



</Grid>
```

Comment: Just do it in the property setter for the property the text box is bound to. You can omit the TwoWay flag since that's the default for that property, but you should add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged so it will update the property every time the user types a character.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works exactly as I wanted to :)
For anyone with similar problem I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 8):

***Ed Plunkett*** gave the simplest solution:

There is no need to write whole bunch of code to implement command while TextChanged occurs, there is a Binding property *UpdateSourceTrigger* which determines when there should be the update, by default it's set to *LostFocus* so it is for example when you click on another control, if you'd like to update it while user is typing, you need to set value to *PropertyChanged* and that's it!

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Weight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: Oh my god, I have been searching for this for weeks. You rule! Thank you!